# Numpy corrcoef error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm now learning Subspace method to categorize handwritten numbers. 
Subspace method needs a self-correlation matrix, and I found `np.corrcoef()` can compute that.

In the documentation of `np.corrcoef()`, it says "each row represents a variable, with observations in the columns" by default. So, I transpose my input data since each row is an observation (4132 obs, 784 vars).

However, the function returns an array with info or NaNs with the transposing. Then, I can't compute eigenvalue and eigenvector.

Without transposing, I can compute perfectly, but that's not I want (a (4132,4132) shape array). I don't understand why this happens.

Here's my code:

```
X = train[train["label"]==i].iloc[:,1:] 
C = np.corrcoef(X.T)
print(np.isnan(np.min(C))) #-> print True if there are Nan values
eig_val,eig_vec = linalg.eigh(C) #-> returns ValueError
print(eig_val.shape,eig_vec.shape)
```

X is like this (4132row,785 columns)

[image: Example of X]

[image: Example of image]

Comment: Please add a minimal example so that we may reproduce your error.

Comment: Thanks Luca. I added some.

Comment: So its just a matrix of zeros?

Comment: Sorry. It's 28*28 pixels of binary images of written numbers.
Each row is consisted with a label and 784 columns of binary value (1 is white and 0 is black )

Comment: Why is the provided example filled with zeros then?

Comment: I added an example of image. 
As you can see, many pixels of the image is filled with zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some of your rows (after transposing) have no variance, hence there are zero-values in the covariance matrix (which you can check with `np.cov`). If you check the docs for `np.corrcoef`, the correlation coefficients have a division by elements from the covariance matrix, hence **division by 0** since some of your rows have no variance.

Comment: Hans, Thank you for your help.
It seems you're right. I'll try to solve the problem with this approach.